# glclearcolor best color?

Tags: opengl, optimization

this might seam like a stupid question but i was wondering, when calling

```
glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

to clear the screen in my opengl project is there any performance differences for using different colors? i mean if for example i clear to red vs blue/green/*insert any color will it impact the performance in any way?

Comment: If it does, then it only depends on some hardware quirk of your local system. You can simply test it, by the way.

Comment: @Jongware i didn't see any difference on my pc, but then again my program isn't really heavy (runes at about 6000 fps :P) but i thought it might on heavier programs because of how LCD/IPS/TN panels work.

Comment: @leejenshil: The GPU cares only about delivering a signal to the display scanout buffer. The display technology used in question has not effect on rendering performance whatsoever. The only interaction between display scanout and the GPU is the framebuffer configuration (size, bit depth) and V-Sync.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No (technically there could be a difference, since OpenGL does not impose any performance requirements on the functioncall).

Btw. you should set the clear color before calling clear.